# Restored iPad , old Apple ID, find my iPhone still on

Tags: ipad, find-my-iphone

So we have a iPad with an old Apple ID that is now disabled, can't get the restore to work because find my iPhone is still on and it keeps asking for the Apple ID and password of this account to turn off the find my iPhone 
I am over it! Just painful, anyone know what to do?
Dee

Answer (score 0):

If the account is truly deleted and you can no longer login, you'll have to contact Apple for them to remove the lock for you. You'll probably need to show proof of purchase, ID or similar.

Comment: You cannot 'delete' an iCloud account. You can abandon it & it will still be there a decade or more later, as I recently rediscovered my old .mac account from the 90s.

Comment: Yes, but as I wrote "you can no longer login" - i.e. it is of no good to you that the account is still there decades later if you haven't got the password or no other means to login (i.e. answers to security questions, access to the email account, etc). In this case you do really have to contact Apple customer service.